# What's the optimal MongoDB architecture for finding documents to which no pointers exist in another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

## Use case

A science fair, with Judges who will sign in to the platform and each create one Score per each Project.

## The Problem We Are Trying To Solve

A Judge would like to visit a URL, say `http://www.judge.com/next` that consistently provides the next Project for which they have not yet created a Score, else inform them (because all Projects have a Score created by that Judge) their judging duties have been fulfilled.

## A Shot In The Dark

Assume three collections, **Judges**, **Projects** and **Scores**.

```
judges: [{
  _id
  name:String
}]

projects: [{
  _id
  name:String
}]

scores: [{
  _id
  type: enum
  judge: _id
  project: _id
}]
```

## Use SQL, Stupid.

Obviously.  But this question is, ***if we had to build it in MongoDB, what would we do?***

## A Shot in the Dawn

Assume two collections, **Judges** and **Projects**.

```
judges: [{
  _id
  name:String
  scores: [{
    _id
    type: enum
    project: _id
  }]
}]

projects: [{
  _id
  name:String
}]
```

## So, what is the The Right Architecture?

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks for the clarity; I've re-written my question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for the clarity; I've re-written my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there isn't a canonical "right" answer for schema design in MongoDB; the best approach depends on your use case and data.

Below are a few ideas using the `mongo` shell and noting some of the caveats.

If either of the final queries does not return a result you know that person's judging duties have been fulfilled. If you want to skip the effort of doing this comparison once judging is complete, you could always set & check a boolean value on the judge (i.e. `doneJudging`).

#### Spot the Difference (approach for *A Shot in The Dark*)

- Assuming sample scores of:

  ```
  db.scores.insert([
     { judge: 123, project: 1, score: 5 },
     { judge: 123, project: 2, score: 6 },
     { judge: 123, project: 3, score: 9 },
     { judge: 123, project: 5, score: 9 },
  ])
  ```
- First, find all the projects that a judge has rated:

  ```
  var rated = db.scores.distinct('project', { judge: 123 })
  ```
- Then find the projects that a judge has *not* rated using the [`$nin` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/):

  ```
  var unrated = db.projects.find({_id: { $nin: rated }})
  ```
- Example result ("all unrated projects for judge with `_id` of 123"):

  ```
   { "_id" : 4, "name" : "Project 4" }
   { "_id" : 6, "name" : "Project 6" }
  ```
- This approach requires two queries to calculate the final result, but also allows you to get a list of all unrated projects for a judge.
- You do not have to update judges as new projects are added; new projects will automatically show up as unrated.

#### I Know What You Judged Last Summer (approach for *A Shot in The Dawn*)

- Before the judging round starts, pre-allocate your `scores` array for each judge & project combination:

  ```
  db.judges.insert(
     {
        _id: 123,
        name: "Bobby Tables",
        scores: [
          { project: 1, score: 5 },
          { project: 2, score: 6 },
          { project: 3, score: 9 },
          { project: 4 },
          { project: 5, score: 9 },
          { project: 6 },
        ]
    }
  ```

  )
- You can update or append to the `scores` array after the judging begins, but a project won't appear as unrated until added to `judges` documents.
- Use an [`$elemMatch` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to find the "next" unrated project for a given judge. The `$elemMatch` projection will only return the first matching element per array.

  ```
  db.judges.findOne(
      // query
      { _id: 123 },
      // projection
      {
         _id: 0,
         scores: {
            $elemMatch: { score: null }
         }
      }
  )
  ```
- Example result ("next unrated project for judge with `_id` 123 to rate"):

  ```
  { "scores" : [ { "project" : 4 } ] }
  ```
- This approach makes it easy to get the "next project" for a judge, but if you want to get all unrated projects you would have to fetch all projects and filter the unrated ones in your application code
- Since each judge has their own list of unrated projects, you could also use this approach to assign a subset of projects to the judges.
- If you add (or remove) projects you will have to update all of the judge documents.